Sieve theory obstruction: prime-sparse and nearly full-differenced sets?
Let $D(A) = {|a-b| : a, b \in A}$ denote the difference set of $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. A set $A \subseteq (x/2, x]$ is almost full-differenced if $|D(A)| \geq \frac{x}{2} - \log x$. Let $C_x$ denote the set of composite numbers in $(x/2, x]$.
Does there exist a constant $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and a sequence of sets $(A_x)_{x \in \mathbb{N}}$, with $A_x \subseteq (x/2,x]$, such that each $A_x$ is almost full-differenced, and for all sufficiently large $x$ satisfies the following two conditions:
$|A_x \cap \mathbb{P}| > (1 - \epsilon)\pi(x) - |C_x|$
$|A_x \cap \mathbb{P}| \leq \epsilon \pi(x)$
Current sieve techniques often incur "losses" when attempting to produce sets with both high prime density and specific additive properties. If prime-sparse, almost full-differenced sets exist, it would imply inherent lower bounds on these losses. For example, consider a classical sieve problem where we seek a lower bound for the sum $\sum_{n \in A} \Lambda(n)$, where $A \subseteq (x/2,x]$ and $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function. A positive solution to our problem might yield a lower bound of the form
$$
\sum_{n \in A} \Lambda(n) \geq (C - \epsilon(x))x$$
where $C$ is a constant determined by the sieve and $\epsilon(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, but with a demonstrably non-trivial lower bound for $\epsilon(x)$ related to the constant $\epsilon$.
Also it seems a positive solution could indicate the existence of prime-repelling structures. Such structures would go beyond simple density considerations. The existence of a prime-sparse, almost full-differenced set would suggest that certain additive configurations of integers inherently hinder the presence of primes, independent of the set's overall size.

i must be missing something, but what is wrong with taking $A_x$ to be all composites in $(x/2,x]$?

@mathworker21: I modified the condition

what? taking $A_x$ to be all composites in $(x/2,x]$ yields $D(A) = x/2$

@mathwork21: I’m new to this field so apologies. I modified the conditions again
